# jquery select all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of checkboxes that are loaded 100 at a time via ajax.

I need this jquery to allow me to have a button when pushed check all on screen. If more are loaded, and the button is pressed, to perhaps toggle all off, then pressed again toggle all back on.

This is what i have, obviously its not working for me.

```
$(function () {
 $('#selectall').click(function () {
  $('#friendslist').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
 });
});
```

The button is `#selectall`, the check boxes are class `.tf`, and they all reside in a parent div called `#check`, inside a div called `#friend`, inside a div called `#friendslist`

Example:

```
<div id='friendslist'>
    <div id='friend'>
        <div id='check'>
            <input type='checkbox' class='tf' name='hurr' value='durr1'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='friend'>
        <div id='check'>
            <input type='checkbox' class='tf' name='hurr' value='durr2'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='friend'>
        <div id='check'>
            <input type='checkbox' class='tf' name='hurr' value='durr3'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type='button' id='selectall' value="Select All">
```

Comment: your HTML is incorrect. `id`s need to be unique per document. It'll still look fine, but you'll run into problems when you start querying it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I know I'm revisiting an old thread, but this page shows up as one of the top results in Google when this question is asked. I am revisiting this because in jQuery 1.6 and above, prop() should be used for "checked" status instead of attr() with true or false being passed. More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

For example, Henrick's code should now be:

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectall').toggle(
        function() {
            $('#friendslist .tf').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('#friendslist .tf').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: attr() was only working the first time I checked & unchecked selectall. prop() works every time, thanks!

Comment: I changed the check marked thingy to this answer so it'll be at the top.

Comment: The toggle event is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Of course, there are various ways around it. Personally, I used a checkbox instead of a button, and the following code: $('#selectall').click(function() {
$('#friendslist .tf').prop('checked', this.checked);  });

Answer (score 13):

Use the jquery toggle function. Then you can also perform whatever other changes you may want to do along with those changes... such as changing the value of the button to say "check all" or "uncheck all".

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectall').toggle(
        function() {
            $('#friendslist .tf').attr('checked', 'checked');
        },
        function() {
            $('#friendslist .tf').attr('checked', '');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: for unchecking you may have to use __attr('checked', false)__ if the given does not work.

Answer (score 12):

```
$('#friendslist .tf')
```

this selector will suit your needs

Answer (score 8):

This is how I toggle checkboxes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Togglebutton').click(function() {
        $('.checkBoxes').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('checked',!$(this).attr('checked'));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

A very simple check/uncheck all without the need of loop

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> Check / Uncheck All

<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="option1" /> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="option2" /> Option 2
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="option3" /> Option 3
```

And the javascript (jQuery) accounting for "undefined" on checkbox value

** **UPDATE - using .prop()** **

```
$("#checkAll").change(function(){
    var status = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;
    $(".chk").prop("checked",status);
});
```

---

** **Previous Suggestion - may not work** **

```
$("#checkAll").change(function(){
    var status = $(this).attr("checked") ? "checked" : false;
    $(".chk").attr("checked",status);
});
```

OR with the suggestion from the next post using .prop() combined into a single line

```
$("#checkAll").change(function(){
    $(".chk").attr("checked",$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

maybe try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectall').click(function () {
        $('#friendslist .tf').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="control-group">
<input type="checkbox" class="selAllChksInGroup"> All
<input type="checkbox" value="NE"> Nebraska
<input type="checkbox" value="FL"> Florida
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){

$("input[type=checkbox].selAllChksInGroup").on("click.chkAll", function( event ){
    $(this).parents('.control-group:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

});
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! It works great on multiple "toggles" on and off. Thanks very much for your help. Old thread, I know, but you still deserve thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I could not get this last example to work for me. The correct way to query the state of the checkbox is apparently :

```
var status = $(this).prop("checked");
```

and not

```
var status = $(this).attr("checked") ? "checked" : false;
```

as above.

See [jQuery receiving checkbox status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645508/jquery-recieving-checkbox-status)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me (IE, Safari, Firefox) by just changing your this.checked to 'checked'.

```
$(function() {
  $('#selectall').click(function() {
    $('#friendslist').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
  });
 });
```

Comment: Henrik's answer also works for me, plus it'll toggle checked/not checked.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
$(function () {
 $('#selectall').click(function () {
  $('#friendslist input:checkbox').attr('checked', checked_status);
 });
});
```

//checked_status=true/false  -as the case may be, or set it via a variable

Answer (score 1):

assuming `#selectall` is a checkbox itself whose state you want copied to all the other checkboxes?

```
$(function () {
 $('#selectall').click(function () {
  $('#friendslist input:checkbox').attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var checkAll = function(){  
var check_all = arguments[0];
var child_class = arguments[1];
if(arguments.length>2){
    var uncheck_all = arguments[2];

    $('#'+check_all).click(function (){
        $('.'+child_class).attr('checked', true);
    });

    $('#'+uncheck_all).click(function (){
        $('.'+child_class).attr('checked', false);
    });

    $('.'+child_class).click(function (){
        var checkall_checked = true;
        $('.'+child_class).each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('checked')!=true){
                checkall_checked = false;
            }
        });
        if(checkall_checked == true){
            $('#'+check_all).attr('checked', true);
            $('#'+uncheck_all).attr('checked', false);
        }else{
            $('#'+check_all).attr('checked', false);
            $('#'+uncheck_all).attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
}else{
    $('#'+check_all).click(function (){
        $('.'+child_class).attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
    });

    $('.'+child_class).click(function (){
        var checkall_checked = true;
        $('.'+child_class).each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('checked')!=true){
                checkall_checked = false;                   
            }
        });
        $('#'+check_all).attr('checked', checkall_checked);
    });
}
};
```

To "check all" and "uncheck all" is same checkbox

checkAll("checkall_id", "child_checkboxes_class_name");

To "check all" and "uncheck all" is separate checkbox

checkAll("checkall_id", "child_checkboxes_class_name", "uncheckall_id");

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I achieved it.

```
function SelectAllCheckBoxes();
{
$('#divSrchResults').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', $('#chkPrint').is(":checked"));
}
```

The following fires the above line.

```
<input type=checkbox id=chkPrint onclick='SelectAllCheckBoxes();' />
```

On the click of chkPrint , every checkbox in the grid divSrchResults' is either checked or unchecked depending on the status of chkPrint.

Of course, if you need advanced functions like unchecking the titled checkbox when every other checkbox has been unchecked, you need to write another function for this.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function that I use on all projects. This is just the initial draft, but maybe it will help:

Function:

```
function selectAll(wrapperAll, wrapperInputs) {

    var selectAll = wrapperAll.find('input');
    var allInputs = wrapperInputs.find('input');

    console.log('Checked inputs = ' + allInputs.filter(':not(:checked)').length);

    function checkitems(allInputs) {
        //If all items checked
        if (allInputs.filter(':not(:checked)').length === 0) {
            console.log('Function: checkItems: All items checked');
            selectAll.attr('checked', true);

        } else {
            console.log('Function: checkItems: Else all items checked');
            selectAll.attr('checked', false);
        }
    }

    checkitems(allInputs);
    allInputs.on('change', function () {
        checkitems(allInputs)
    });

    selectAll.on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            console.log('This checkbox is checked');
            wrapperInputs.find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);

        } else {
            console.log('This checkbox is NOT checked');
            wrapperInputs.find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);

        }
    });

}
```

It accepts the 2 parameters where the inputs are wrapped into and you cand use-it like this:

```
$(function () {

    var wrapperAll = $('.selectallinput');
    var wrapperInputs = $('.inputs');

    selectAll(wrapperAll, wrapperInputs);
});
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cHD9z/

Comment: I like that the code is written in a way that is reusable, however, I don't like the name of `selectAll`; I chose `bindSelectAll` instead.

Comment: True, I should use a better name. If you use this make sure that if you are using jQuery 1.9 you change .attr('checked', false) with  .prop('checked', false)

Answer (score 0):

So "checked" is a crappy attribute; in many browsers it doesn't work as expected :-(  Try doing:

```
$('#friendslist').find(':checkbox')
    .attr('checked', this.checked)
    .attr('defaultChecked', this.checked);
```

I know setting "defaultChecked" doesn't make any sense, but try it and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)"> Select / Deselect All

Now here are  two versions of the toggleChecked function dependent on the semantics of your document. The only real difference is the jQuery selector for your list checkboxes:

1: All checkboxes have a class of  “checkbox” (<input type=”checkbox” class=”checkbox” />)
function toggleChecked(status) {
$(".checkbox").each( function() {
$(this).attr("checked",status);
})
}

2: All the checkboxes are contained within a div with an arbitary id:

<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
</div>

In this case the function would look like this:

function toggleChecked(status) {
$("#checkboxes input").each( function() {
$(this).attr("checked",status);
})

Have fun!
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for both (checked/unchecked) **selectall** situations:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#selectall').click(function () {
   $("#friendslist .tf").attr("checked",function(){return $(this).attr("checked") ? false : true;});
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9223856/552438) won't work for jQuery 1.9+. The event handling aspect of the (rather heavily) overloaded `.toggle()` function was removed in that version, which means that attempting to call `.toggle(function, function)` will instead just toggle the display state of your element.

I'd suggest doing something like this instead:

```
$(function() {
    var selectAll = $('#selectall');
    selectAll.on('click', function(e) {
        var checked = !(selectAll.data('checked') || false);
        $('#friendslist .tf').prop('checked', checked);
        selectAll.data('checked', checked);
    });
});
```

That uses a regular click event handler, plus a data attribute to track the "toggled" status and invert it with each click.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic jQuery plugin I wrote that selects all checkboxes on the page, except the checkbox/element that is to be used as the toggle. This, of course, could be amended to suit your needs:

```
(function($) {
    // Checkbox toggle function for selecting all checkboxes on the page
    $.fn.toggleCheckboxes = function() {
        // Get all checkbox elements
        checkboxes = $(':checkbox').not(this);

        // Check if the checkboxes are checked/unchecked and if so uncheck/check them
        if(this.is(':checked')) {
            checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Then simply call the function on your checkbox or button element:

```
// Check all checkboxes
$('.check-all').change(function() {
    $(this).toggleCheckboxes();
});
```

As you are adding and removing more checkboxes via AJAX, you may want to use this instead of .change():

```
// Check all checkboxes
$(document).on('change', '.check-all', function() {
    $(this).toggleCheckboxes();
});
```