# jQuery receiving checkbox status

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm changing checkbox status this way: `$(this).attr("checked", 'checked');`

After this I want to receive checkbox status, but I got this:

```
$(this).attr('checked'): "checked"
$(this).is(':checked'): false
```

How this can be?

P.S. Maybe I'm not correctly changing checkbox status via jQuery?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The proper way is `$(this).prop('checked')` to return the boolean *property* instead of the attribute (which is a a string).

Using `.prop()` you can also *set* the checked state: `$(this).prop('checked', true_or_false);`

As you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/QR2fL/, `.attr('checked')` returns the initial value of the attribute - it does not changed when checking/unchecking the checkbox.

Answer (score 8):

You should not check the checkbox like this:

```
$(this).attr("checked", 'checked');
```

but like this

```
$(this).prop("checked", true);
```

To check if a checkbox is checked you can use:

```
$(this).prop('checked');
```

or

```
$(this).is(':checked');
```

which return a boolean proerty