# Adding a Select All Checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

I want to add a check/uncheck all button for this script:

php:

```
require_once('includes/commons.php');

$query_get_addresses = 'SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name ASC';
$result_get_addresses = mysql_query($query_get_addresses);
$addresses_count = mysql_num_rows($result_get_addresses);

?>
```

script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // initialize
    var recipient = $('input[name=recipient]').val();
    var recipient_array = new Array();
    if(recipient != '') {
        recipient_array = recipient.split(',');
        for(var i = 0; i < recipient_array.length; i++) {
            recipient_array[i] = $.trim(recipient_array[i]);

            if(recipient_array[i] == '')
                recipient_array.splice(i, 1);
        }

        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
            if($.inArray(this.value, recipient_array) >= 0) {
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
            }
        });
    }
    // add and/or remove
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        var recipient_list = '';

        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
            var index = $.inArray(this.value, recipient_array);
            if(this.checked) {
                if(index < 0)
                    recipient_array.push(this.value);
            }
            else {
                if(index >= 0) {
                    recipient_array.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        });

        $('input[name=recipient]').val(recipient_array);
    });
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<h2>Choose recipient</h2>
<div><?php

if($addresses_count > 0) {

    ?><form name="select-recipient-form"><ul><?php

        while($row_get_addresses = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_get_addresses)) {
            $row_get_addresses = unsanitize($row_get_addresses);

            ?><li><input type="checkbox" name="recipient[]" id="recipient-1" value="<?php echo $row_get_addresses['recipient']; ?>" /><label for="recipient-1"><?php echo $row_get_addresses['first_name'].' '.$row_get_addresses['last_name'].' &lt;'.$row_get_addresses['recipient'].'&gt;'; ?></label></li><?php
        }

    ?></ul>
    </form><br /><?php

} else {

    ?><p>You don't have any contacts.</p><?php
}

?>
</div>
```

I have tried to follow some guides. Like [this one](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-checkall.php) for example but I can't get it to work.
Any idea how I can achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: please note that the "id" attribute of the checkbox should be distinct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880313/jquery-select-all-checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#form1').ready(function(){
    $('.gumb:button').toggle(function(){
        $('.tocheck ').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
    },function(){
        $('.tocheck ').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})

</script>

<input type="button" class="gumb" value="check all" />
<input name="checkbox[]" class="tocheck" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rows['member_id'] ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to you check boxes and then use:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-class" ... />
    ...
    <button type="button" class="check-all">Check All</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var checked = false;
        $('button.check-all').click(function() {
            checked = !checked;
            $('.checkbox-class').prop('checked', checked); // jQuery 1.6+
            if (checked) $(this).text('Uncheck All');
            else $(this).text('Check All);
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: for jQuery<1.6 use `$('.checkbox-class').attr('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: @Mithun actually, it should be `$('.checkbox-class').attr('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. But how about an uncheck button. In an example on this page [link](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-checkall.php)  they combined the check/uncheck button by using only one button.

Comment: you can add a check to see whether atleast one of the checkbox is checked if true then fire `$('.checkbox-class').removeAttr('checked');` else fire `$('.checkbox-class').attr('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: you can do that check by this code `if ($('.checkbox-class:checked').length) {
    $('.checkbox-class').removeAttr('checked');
   } else {
    $('.checkbox-class').attr('checked', 'checked');
   }`

Comment: @Dreni See my updated answer for a check/uncheck all toggle state button.

Comment: @Petah Thanks, works great. As you can see on my example above, the values that are checked are sent as values to a different page. When I manually select the checkboxes it works great but with your example, it only checks/unchecks the checkboxes, it does not send the values. Can you see my example above and combine the same function to your solution. Thanks

Comment: @Dreni I don't understand exactly what you need, if you could make a jsfiddle with what you want, Ill help out more... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Petah, the script I'm working on is a messaging script. This is the **compose.php** file [link](http://pastebin.com/3qD7BQ1V) which is used to send a message. To choose a recipient a popup(facebox) shows up which is this file **address-book-view.php** [link](http://pastebin.com/cxQEFssG). In the first javascript section in the address-book-view file there is a function that passes the checked values to the compose.php file.By checking a checkbox it send the value of the checkbox back to the compose.php file.Now I want a button that when checked,sends all the checked values to the compose file

Comment: @Dreni, no, I am not going to debug 500 lines of your code for free.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" />check all</span>
```

Add a class to all your checkboxes except the check all check box

```
<input type="checkbox" class="tocheck ... />
    ...
    ....

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.checkall').click(function() {
    $('.tocheck ').attr('checked', true); 
});
});
```

Comment: Hi @coolguy.. this is working fine to select the checkboxes, but not working to deselect.. i even tried with `removeAttr`, but its not working.. do u have any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If following is the HTML
    `<input class="checkbox-class" type="checkbox" value="1" /><input class="checkbox-class" type="checkbox" value="2" />
    <input class="checkbox-class" type="checkbox" value="3" />
    <input type="button" id="clickit" value="Check All" />`

JS will do the job

```
$("#clickit").click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Check All') {
        $('.checkbox-class').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $(this).val('Uncheck All');
    } else {
        $('.checkbox-class').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('Check All');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine with me

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#select_all").change(function(){
  $(".checkbox_class").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
  });
});
</script>
```

you only need to add class **checkbox_class** to all checkbox

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selecctall">

<input class="checkbox_class" name="recipient[]" value="'.$recipientId.'" type="checkbox" />
```

Easy and simple :D

Answer (score 0):

Only that worked for me (btw uses checkbox, not button)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_all').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
             $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });

    $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
        if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
        }else{
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>


<ul class="main">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /> Select all</li>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"/>Item 1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2"/>Item 2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="3"/>Item 3</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="4"/>Item 4</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="5"/>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check-uncheck all / select-unselect all checkboxes Follow the following code , its really simple with the following code

inside your html form add the following line of code

```
<input type="checkbox" id='checkall' /> Select All
```

and use the following script code

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   // Check or Uncheck All checkboxes
   $("#checkall").change(function(){
     var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
     if(checked){
       $(".checkbox").each(function(){
         $(this).prop("checked",true);
       });
     }else{
       $(".checkbox").each(function(){
         $(this).prop("checked",false);
       });
     }
   });
 
  // Changing state of CheckAll checkbox 
  $(".checkbox").click(function(){
 
    if($(".checkbox").length == $(".checkbox:checked").length) {
      $("#checkall").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("#checkall").removeAttr("checked");
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

keep in mind that .checkbox in script code is the class name from other checkboxes of html form

for example if you have input checkbox as following

```
<input class="checkbox" name="emailid[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $email;?>" />
```