# When using jquery '.toggle' input element is being hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want a 'select all' checkbox that checks / unchecks all other checkboxes when clicked.

I am using this script from another Stack Overflow question ([jquery select all checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880313/jquery-select-all-checkboxes))

```
$(function () {
  $('#select-all').toggle(
    function() {
        $('.subscription-type').prop('checked', true);
    },
    function() {
        $('.subscription-type').prop('checked', false);
    }
  );
});
```

For some reason, this applies 'display: none' to my checkbox.  Why???

[image: <input> getting 'display: none' applied]

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wihor/1/edit)**

Comment: toogle is animation function: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ you should use change event with `$(this).is(':checked');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) or [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#select-all').click(
      function(){
        $('.subscription-type').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
      });
});
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/vefaziqo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The toggle event, as you're trying to use it, was deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

The current toggle is just a hide/show function