# jquery check all checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I used [jquery select all checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880313/jquery-select-all-checkboxes) to try and get a check all checkboxes button.  Using the code from this answer, My button disappears immediately as seen on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0bpdr53/)

JS:

```
$(function(){

    $('#checkAll').toggle(
            function(){
                    $('#numberList .numberClass').prop('checked',true);
            },
            function(){
                    $('#numberList .numberClass').prop('checked',false);
            });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id='numberList'>
 <table>
<tr>
<th>
    <input type='button' id='checkAll' name='checkAll' value='Check All'>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input class='numberClass' type='checkbox' id='number[" . $k . "]' name='number[" . $k . "]'>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input class='numberClass' type='checkbox' id='number[" . $k . "]' name='number[" . $k . "]'>
</td></tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

what is so obvious that i am missing?

Comment: Try `$('#checkAll').click(`

Answer (score 4):

The `.toggle(function, function)` version (i.e. the event handling aspect) was removed in jQuery 1.9, as stated in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). As such, it's treating it as the other [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method, which is used to toggle the visibility of a set of elements - since it's set to visible with your HTML and CSS, jQuery is toggling it to not being visible.

Comment: ahh, thats an old post i was using.  thanks. will accept in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the `toggle()` function? The description in the jQuery documentation clearly states:

> Display or hide the matched elements.

Have a look at the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o0bpdr53/12/

Comment: I kind of want to downvote just for using `0` and `1` to track a boolean state in a language that supports boolean `true` and `false` values... Use an actual boolean and you can get rid of the `if` statement entirely: http://jsfiddle.net/o0bpdr53/14/

Answer (score 0):

As Anthony said, using `.toggle` in the way you are here was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9. `.toggle` now toggles element visibility, which is why you're seeing the button disappear.

Reading [the source for the now-removed `.toggle` in jQuery 1.8](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.1/src/event.js#L980) could give a clue to fixing this. One way, to avoid global variables, would be to use `.data()` to store the current state of the checkboxes:

```
$('#checkAll').click(
    function () {
        var currentlyChecked = $(this).data('checked') || false,
            shouldBecomeChecked = !currentlyChecked;

        $('#numberList .numberClass').prop('checked', shouldBecomeChecked);

        $(this).data('checked', shouldBecomeChecked);
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o0bpdr53/15/

Answer (score 0):

My solution was the following:

```
        $('#checkAll').change(

            function(){
                    if ($(this).prop('checked')){
                            var status = true;
                    }
                    else{
                            var status = false;
                    }
                            $('.numberClass').prop('checked',status);
            });
```

Thanks to all the commenters.